# how to run .py 3 files on Mac and Windows without installing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, macos

Quick question on running .py files on Mac and Windows.

For Mac I was wondering if I added the automatic startup function (so that it runs since the startup automatically), since I am writing in python 3 it wouldn’t even run because from my understanding Mac comes with python 2 pre installed and not 3. So how could I go around this problem so that it runs as it should, without having to install python 3 on the Mac itself.

For Windows it is kinda of the same, Windows doesn’t come with python pre installed so what is the best way to go about solving this problem again without downloading python 3 on the computer.

Comment: You can't run Python scripts without installing Python.

Comment: Your .py file (script) might have implemented to compatible with python 2 and 3 both. Therefore it's running on python 2 even you have implemented it on python 3 
[How to write python code to compatible with python 2 and 3 both](https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html).

You can verify the installed python version by running "python" command in shell.